# Compute "less-than count" on df column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My raw data is as follows:

```
id_2    column_A
602     1
602     1
602     1
602     1
602     3
602     8
602     15
602
602
```

My dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv('xxyy.csv')    
df = df.fillna(np.nan)
```

My requirement is:
I have to find the less than count for each value for `ex:(for 1 its 0, for 3 its 4,etc)`

EDIT:

```
def func1(value):                   
    return df['column_A'][df['column_A'] < value].count()

for name, df in df.groupby(['id_2']):
    for j in df.index:
       y = func1(df['column_A'].ix[j])   
       print y
```

what i am getting is:

for 3 its 5, for 8 its 6, for 15 its 4, what should i want is:
for 3 it should be 6, for 8 it should be 7, for 15 it should be 8 (included 2 nan)

Comment: Can you post raw input data and code to reproduce your df, also it's unclear what you're attempting here what is less than count mean here?

Comment: Subburaj: **post the code needed to reproduce that df**, like people are asking you.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Sorry are you asking for the row count for the df when the value of `column_A` is less than X value?

Comment: @Subburaj, which is your actual data, your df and raw data look different?

Comment: @Subburaj, do you mean `print((df["column_A"]).dropna()<15).sum()`?

Comment: @Subburaj. have you tried it?

Comment: Can you please update the question with what exactly you are getting now? and what exactly you expect>?

Comment: So how does my answer not answer your question?

Comment: do you mean something like `[(x, (df["column_A"] < x).sum()) for x in df["column_A"].unique()])`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then you can just filter the df and call `count`:

```
In [52]:
df[df['column_A'] < 3].count()

Out[52]:
column_A    4
id_2        4
dtype: int64

In [54]:
df[df['column_A'] < 8].count()

Out[54]:
column_A    5
id_2        5
dtype: int64

In [55]:
df[df['column_A'] < 15].count()

Out[55]:
column_A    6
id_2        6
dtype: int64
```

You can wrap this in a func and pass your desired value:

```
In [56]:
def func(x):
    return df[df['column_A'] < x].count()
​
func(3)

Out[56]:
column_A    4
id_2        4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: this is want i tried 'print (df['column_A'][df['column_A'] < df['column_A'].ix[j]].count())', but y ts printing wrong count??

Comment: Because your first 4 column_A values are just 1 when you do `df['column_A'].ix[j]` you are returning 'column_A' values at that index, you could've done some basic debugging

Comment: @ EdChum i am new to this python and pandas world. Can you please explain bit more?? what i have to do instead of this df['column_A'].ix[j]??

Comment: Explain what? **You** need to explain what you don't understand, I'm not here to guess or read your mind

Comment: I got the error:  SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2'

Comment: Please edit your post with your code and full stack trace, telling me the error without the full context is a waste of my time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81860/discussion-between-subburaj-and-edchum).